# Changing AES key of encrypted file without decrypt/re-encrypting it

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I made an application that encrypts and stores files in JAVA.
I have lots of files that are encrypted using AES.
I have four access levels & four KEYs and I want to encrypt each file with its access level specific KEY; I need changing the KEY to make user to be able to change access level of file.
Is it possible to change this key only by providing previous key and without decrypting files and then re-encrypt them?

Comment: Are you sure that only AES is involved? Or is it rather a hybrid encryption, which uses AES to encrypt the real key for the (then-symmetric) encryption?

Comment: @cyroxx: yes, it is only AES , I wrote to encrypting class by myself.

Comment: Why do you need change the AES key?

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree: I added the reason that I mentioned as a comment to Bugari's answer to the Question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You'll have to re-encrypt your files.

Comment: Yep, the only way around this was using file specific keys in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Well, maybe you could have constant key that encrypts files, that will be encrypted again, with the key you can change? this way only thing that will have to be decrypted and encrypted again will be your key :)

It's not good for every case, but there are some where that should do the trick.

Comment: Your idea is very interesting; but as you said it is not suitable for all cases (as mine); I have four access levels & four KEYs and I want to encrypt each file with its access level specific KEY; I need changing the KEY to make user to be able to change access level of file. so your idea will not work. nevertheless thanks for the nice idea.

Comment: @4r1y4n think again - what you describe can be implemented using several levels of constant keys.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: How? By using 4 constant KEYs files of each level still are encoded with different KEY than the others and  changing the access level still needs KEY change and re-encode of files!

Comment: This *is* the way to do it, but it won't work on the files already encrypted. As *nothing* will allow you to change the keys on the currently encrypted files short of fully decrypting/encrypting them, it's still the most efficient answer. Or you could just take tibtof's answer.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to *not* directly encrypt each file with the master key for that "level" - instead, generate a different random "file key" for each file and encrypt the file with that.  You then encrypt the file key with the level key, and store the result with the file.

When you want to change the level of a file, you only need to decrypt and re-encrypt the file key, not the entire file itself.